# it says incorrect syntax near begin?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Write an SQL Function named 'Find_customer_detail' which takes the customer id as input and returns the first name,last name and phone number concatenated with a space between them, if a customer exists for the input id, else returns error message as 'Customer Not Available'.

```
$create function Find_customer_detail(@id int)
returns varchar(100) as
begin try
declare @first_name varchar(30),@last_name varchar(30),@phone_number varchar(30)
select @first_name=first_name,@last_name=last_name,@phone_number=phone_number from customer
where id=@id
return (@first_name+' '+@last_name+' '+@phone_number)
end try
begin catch
print 'Customer not available'
end catch
go
```

Comment: It does indeed report a syntax error. Did you look at the [documented syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax)? Notice that a scalar-valued function's body must be surrounded by a `BEGIN`/`END` block, and those are different to similar blocks such as `BEGIN TRY`.

Comment: A [note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#interoperability) about `TRY...CATCH` block: *The following statements are valid in a function: ...Control-of-Flow statements except TRY...CATCH statements. ...*

Comment: i have tried adding begin and end and but it still leads to error

Comment: I strongly suggest you consider an inline Table Valued Function, which performs much faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to fix. `TRY/CATCH` blocks aren't allowed in functions but even if they were, it should be `BEGIN ... BEGIN TRY ... END TRY BEGIN CATCH ... END CATCH ... END`. You need an explicit `RETURN` statement so the function knows what to return.
`PRINT` statements aren't allowed in functions.
Functions in TSQL must be deterministic which means given the same input and the same state of the data, it must always return the same result. They also cannot have "side effects" which is why `PRINT` is not allowed.

You can check the return value, if it is `null` you know that the record wasn't found so you handle the error when the function returns.

I added `ISNULL` on the columns so that `@result` is always not-null when the record is found, so the only way `@result` can be `null` is if the record wasn't found.

```
create function Find_customer_detail(@id int) 
    returns varchar(100) as 
    begin 
    declare @result varchar(100)
    select @result=isnull(first_name,'') 
           + ' ' + isnull(last_name, '') 
           + ' ' + isnull(phone_number, '')
    from customer 
    where id=@id 
    return @result
    end
```

Comment: how to add the 'customer not available error'..how it could be added in this program

Comment: You could `return ISNULL(@result, 'Customer not available')` and then check if `@result` equals 'Customer not available'.

Comment: Just a caution: it's not usually a good idea to mix error messages with valid results from a function because your error message could be a valid result. In your case, it's reasonably safe, unless someone enters a customer record with first_name = 'Customer', last_name = 'not' and phone_number = 'available'. Don't laugh, I've seen this sort of thing happen :)